# $(1-x)^y ≈ e^{-xy}$

Tags: approximation, exponential-function, approximation-theory

Here is an approximation I often see in biology articles but don't really understand:

$$(1-x)^y ≈ e^{-xy}$$

I think this $e^{-xy}$ closely approximates $(1-x)^y$ whenever $x$ is small. Can you help me to understand the conditions for this approximation and why this approximation holds true.

Comment: The basic reason for this is that $1-x\approx e^{-x}$ when $x$ is small. So $(1-x)^y\approx e^{-xy}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with real exponents, it is useful to come back to the definition:

We have $(1-x)^y=e^{y\ln(1-x)}$

but, when $x$ is small, $\ln(1-x)\approx -x$ (since the tangent to the graph $y=\ln(1-x)$ has equation $y=-x$), so for any $y$ and for any $x$ small,

we obtain $y\ln(1-x)\approx -xy$.

Using the continuity of $\exp$, we obtain $(1-x)^y\approx e^{-xy}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have by the Taylor series 
$$(1-x)^y\sim_01-yx$$
and
$$e^{-xy}\sim_0 1-xy$$
so we have the given approximation.

Comment: I tried to find $(1-x)^y$ from expanding $e^{-xy}$ in series but I didn't realize that they both expand to $1-xy$. Thank you! What is the strict meaning of $\sim_0$? Is it "evaluated at $\text{some_variable}=0$"?

Comment: $\sim_0$ means "asymptotically equal at $0$" and for example we write $\sin x\sim_0 x$ and this is equivalent to say
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Comment: $\sim$ isn't really the right notion here, considering it's also true that $e^{-xy} \sim 1 - 100x$ as $x \to 0$.  This argument should probably be reworked to use O-notation.

Comment: I didn't understand you! $e^{-xy}\sim 1-100xy$ isn't true.@AntonioVargas

Comment: Uh... yes it is.  Do you not believe that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-xy}}{1-100xy} = 1?$$

Comment: haha Did you try to give me a counterexample? Ok the definition that I gave is the preliminary definition for the novice but if we are familiar with this concept then the definition is
$$f(x)\sim_a g(x)\iff f(x)-g(x)=_a o(f(x))\iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, |x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon|f(x)|$$ @AntonioVargas

Comment: If you take $f(x) = e^{-xy}$ and $g(x) = 1-100xy$ then $f(x) - g(x) = e^{-xy} - 1 + 100xy = o(1) = o(e^{-xy}) = o(f(x))$ as $x \to 0$, satisfying your definition.  Please consider my objection more closely, as I am not a novice either.